# I've been trying to make a game in PyGame, and the collision detector is not working

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to learn the basics of PyGame, so I've been trying to make a very basic game. The game (should) consist of a red square that moves around and loses if it hits one of the blue squares falling from the sky. Everything works properly, except for the collision detector, which doesn't detect anything. Can anyone help me? Here's the code:

```py
import pygame as pg
import sys
import random as rd

pg.init()

winWidth = 850
winHeight = 600
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
speed = 10
player_pos = [int(winWidth/2-25), winHeight-100]
enemyList = []

clock = pg.time.Clock()
win = pg.display.set_mode((winWidth, winHeight))
pg.display.set_caption('Game')

# creates the position of the enemy and returns it
def createEnemy():
    enemy = [rd.randrange(0, winWidth-50, 50), 0]
    return enemy

# draws an enemy in the position received
def drawEnemy(enemy_pos):
    pg.draw.rect(win, blue, (enemy_pos[0], enemy_pos[1], 50, 50))

# if the enemy is inside the screen, it is moved downwards.
# else, it is deleted from the list.
def updateEnemy(enemy_pos):
    if 0 <= enemy_pos[1] < winHeight:
        enemy_pos[1] += speed
    else:
        enemyList.remove(enemy_pos)

# detects collisions
def collisionDetector(enemy):
    if enemy[0] == player_pos[0] and enemy[1] >= player_pos[1] + 50 >= enemy[1] + 50:
        return True
    elif enemy[0] == player_pos[0] and enemy[1] >= player_pos[1] >= enemy[1] + 50:
        return True
    return False


while True:
    # keeps 10 enemies on screen always
    while len(enemyList) < 11:
        enemyList.append(createEnemy())

    # moves the player
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                player_pos[0] -= 50
            elif event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                player_pos[0] += 50

    for enemy_pos in enemyList:
        updateEnemy(enemy_pos)

    for enemy in enemyList:
        if collisionDetector(enemy):
            sys.exit()

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pg.draw.rect(win, red, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], 50, 50))
    for enemy_pos in enemyList:
        drawEnemy(enemy_pos)

    clock.tick(30)
    pg.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-check your collision detection conditions. This worked but it needs fine tuning.

```
if enemy[0] == player_pos[0] and enemy[1] <= player_pos[1] + 50 <= enemy[1] + 50:
    return True
elif enemy[0] == player_pos[0] and enemy[1] <= player_pos[1] <= enemy[1] + 50:
    return True
return False
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If that was what you are looking for accept my answer. Have fun programming. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and [`.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to check for the collision of to rectangles:

```py
# detects collisions
def collisionDetector(enemy):
    playerRect = pg.Rect(*player_pos, 50, 50)
    enemyRect = pg.Rect(*enemy, 50, 50)
    return playerRect.colliderect(enemyRect)
```